Multiple ManyToOne relationship raised not mapped to a single property error
I have 3 entity class
Parameter entity class with multiple ManytoOne relationship.
Entity class below
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_gcg_parameter")
public class GcgParameter extends Common implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private Integer parameterId;
    private String gcgParameterName;
    private Double aspectWeightage;
    
    private Integer month;
    private Integer year;
    private String status;
    private String categoryCode;
    
    private GcgAspect gcgAspect;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    
    @Column(name="p_id")
    public Integer getParameterId() {
        return parameterId;
    }
    public void setParameterId(Integer parameterId) {
        this.parameterId = parameterId;
    }
    
    
    @Column(name="gcg_parameter_name")
    public String getGcgParameterName() {
        return gcgParameterName;
    }
    public void setGcgParameterName(String gcgParameterName) {
        this.gcgParameterName = gcgParameterName;
    }
    
        
    @Column(name="aspect_weightage")
    public Double getAspectWeightage() {
        return aspectWeightage;
    }
    public void setAspectWeightage(Double aspectWeightage) {
        this.aspectWeightage = aspectWeightage;
    }
    
    @Column(name="gcg_parameter_month")
    public Integer getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public void setMonth(Integer month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
    
    @Column(name="gcg_parameter_year")
    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    
    @Column(name="status")
    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    
    @Column(name="category_code")
    public String getCategoryCode() {
        return categoryCode;
    }
    public void setCategoryCode(String categoryCode) {
        this.categoryCode = categoryCode;
    }
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "aspect_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public GcgAspect getGcgAspect() {
        return gcgAspect;
    }
    public void setGcgAspect(GcgAspect gcgAspect) {
        this.gcgAspect = gcgAspect;
    }
}

Indicator entity class
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_gcg_parameter_indicator")
public class GcgParameterIndicator extends Common implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private Integer indicatorId;

    private GcgParameter gcgParameter;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public void setIndicatorId(Integer indicatorId) {
        this.indicatorId = indicatorId;
    }
    @Column(name="i_id")
    public Integer getIndicatorId() {
        return indicatorId;
    }
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="gcg_parameter_id", referencedColumnName="p_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="gcg_indicator_month", referencedColumnName="gcg_parameter_month"),
        @JoinColumn(name="gcg_indicator_year", referencedColumnName="gcg_parameter_year")
    })
    public GcgParameter getGcgParameter() {
        return gcgParameter;
    }
    public void setGcgParameter(GcgParameter gcgParameter) {
        this.gcgParameter = gcgParameter;
    }
}

Threshold entity class
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_gcg_parameter_indicator_threshold")
public class GcgIndicatorThreshold extends Common implements Serializable{

    private Integer id;
    private GcgParameterIndicator gcgParameterIndicator;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="gcg_indicator_id", referencedColumnName="i_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="gcg_threshold_month", referencedColumnName="gcg_indicator_month"),
        @JoinColumn(name="gcg_threshold_year", referencedColumnName="gcg_indicator_year")
    })
    public GcgParameterIndicator getGcgParameterIndicator() {
        return gcgParameterIndicator;
    }

    public void setGcgParameterIndicator(GcgParameterIndicator gcgParameterIndicator) {
        this.gcgParameterIndicator = gcgParameterIndicator;
    }
}


When I run app, I got this error
 referencedColumnNames(i_id, gcg_indicator_month, gcg_indicator_year) of GcgIndicatorThreshold.gcgParameterIndicator referencing 
 GcgParameterIndicator not mapped to a single property

I have googled some stuff but does not lead to any solution yet since no similiar case that i faced.
Does anyone have any insight how to solve that issue?

First of all, it's rather odd to have the JPA mappings on the getters instead of the fields.

You appear to have omitted the source for GcgAspect
